# How to add filename as attribute of shp file in FME?

Tags: fme-form

I'm not familiar with FME, so normally I only use auto-generate.

Because I need to extract the filename and put it as an attribute in the shp file, so I try to add the transformer like this.

[image]

But the ouput file is duplicate data like this

How do I fix that?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your dataflow you have split the data into two streams so you are writing each feature twice.

To fix:

1. Remove the connection between your reader and the geometryfilter.
2. Change the output of the filename extracter to connect  **into** the
   geometryfilter.